# Wordpress blog post title does not link to post

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress theme and trying to style my blog page. The titles of each blog do not link to the full individual respective blog posts. Can someone please tell me how to do this? I'm very new to wordpress and am not sure where to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for `<?php the_permalink() ?>` which is a block of PHP meant to be used inside the Wordpress Loop.

[Wordpress Codex for the Permalink Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink)

The usage is explained in there, but essentially, if you're inside the loop (that is, you're iterating over your posts and Wordpress is spitting them out with PHP) you can do something like this

`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>`

Obviously I'm a little rusty and I'm not sure if `the_title()` is syntactically correct, but the idea behind this all is that you want to use these small snippets of PHP in order to better the presentation of your posts.

Hope that gets you started on the right track!

EDIT: If you're, however, NOT using the loop, there's an equivalent function `get_permalink()` [found here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

It's worth noting that it doesn't DISPLAY the link, so you'll have to use an `echo` in order to output the return value of `the_permalink();` AGAIN, this is the method of getting the permalink if you're NOT [looping through your posts and outputting them](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
```

Look at the code, follow exactly the html and php. you may also see the wordpress example theme. you may be just doing like this :

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

If you paste your code, we can say exactly what was the problem.